# Running angular app using nginx server using different path url

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, nginx

hope you are doing well. I have an angular app that I want to run using the nginx server on the Kubernetes cluster, the application is only accessible using the url as http://localhost:4200/ticket/digital.
The problem is when I run the app on the cluster it is saying nginx 404. Below is the required script.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist/air-invoice /usr/share/nginx/html
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    sendfile        on;
    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /_health {
            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        location /ticket/invoice {
           alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /ticket/invoice/index.html;
        }    

        location / {
            location ~ / {
                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
            }
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tickets-virtual-service
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - 'ticket.example.com'
  gateways:
    - istio-system/co-za-landing-ingressgateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri: 
        prefix: /ticket/digital
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: digital-ticket-svc.digital-ticket-ns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
    retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 60s

  - match:
    - uri: 
        prefix: /ticket/invoice
    rewrite: 
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: invoice-ticket-svc.invoice-ticket-ns.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
    retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 60s
```

Thanks, please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Trust an istio gateway is declared with host ‘ ticket.example.com’.

Comment: The gateway setup correctly, I just put example here, to demonstrate easily.

Comment: in the nginx configuration provided there is no configuration or redirection logic to send the request from nginx to istio.   the try_files logic is trying process the request within nginx for /ticket/digital path.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I updated the nginx.conf and a virtual to access the application with /. but I must want the user to give /ticket/digital and /ticket/invoice to define a separate route.